# Adding multiple Authorization to the same routes in nodejs, express and jwt

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, jwt, authorization

I am fairly new to nodejs/express, I created two different user type in separate collection.
I was wondering if there was a way i can add multiple authorisation to the same router method in nodejs express with jwt.
Such that i can do something like this

```
Router.get('/', [Auth1, Auth2], (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello world');
})
```

Basically different authorize user for the same routes.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

In this case if Auth1 and Auth2 are passed then only we will get 'hello world'.

If there are 2 different type of users, I would recommend to use something like this,

```
Router.get('/', authenticateUser([user1, user2]), (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello world');
})
```

and add your user authentication logic in 'authenticateUser' middleware.

If you are using JWT then you can just simply authenticate it with scope claims.